# Problem with boundary condition for the differential equation of a cooling Cube and Sphere

Tags: thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, cooling

Lets considere a sphere of radius $R$ in a temperature $u_0$ which is cooling in an environment of temperature $u_\infty$ (**Note:** I already solved it). I have to solve a diferential equation and one of its conditions is

$-k_s\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=h(u-u_\infty)$, for $r=R.$

And I think it has to be with the heat transfer within the sphere and its surface with the environment, but I dont know what it means, and that is **one of my questions**.

And my other **question** is how to rewrite this condition for a parallelepiped with sides $2a,2b,2c$?.

Comment: Are you asking for the physical interpretation of this equation?

Comment: Yes, for the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation matches the value of the heat flux at the surface of the body inside the body with the value of the heat flux at the surface outside the body.  The left hand side of the equation is the heat flux at the surface inside the body, and is equal to the thermal conductivity times the temperature gradient at the surface.  The right hand side of the equation is the heat flux at the surface outside the body, and is equal to the heat transfer coefficient h times the temperature difference between the surface and the ambient surroundings $u_{\infty}$.

For the answer to your second question, you use the exact same equation as above  *at each surface* of the rectangular parallelopiped ($\pm a$, $\pm b$, $\pm c$) with the following difference:  in place of r in the derivative, you use the coordinate normal to the surface.

Comment: ok, then for example, for one of the surfaces it'll be: $-k_s\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=h(u-u_\infty)$, for $x=a$, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  You are exactly right.